# ClassCircularityError thrown by ClassLoader.defineClass

Tags: java, circular-dependency, classloader

I'm loading classes using a custom class loader.  For the most part, everything works, but sometimes when I load particularly complex projects/libraries, I get a strange bug:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: 
  org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466)
    at my.custom.class.Loader.loadClass(...)
```

Looking at the Javadocs, I wouldn't expect `defineClass` to throw this particular error.  `org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex` is the class I'm trying to load. It's almost as if `defineClass` wants a copy of the class before it'll define the class - which makes no sense to me.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you show your code? Did you just overwrite findClass() as recommended? Otherwise you have to be quite careful to get everything right.

Comment: *It's almost like define class wants a copy of the class before it'll define the class*, no it doesn't want a copy of the class. And how did you managed to define a package name `class`?

Comment: @bestsss presumably the stack trace is just obfuscated with a poor choice of package names

Comment: @bkail, I understand that, it was a sarcastic remark since the stack trace actually misses the important data of the cyclic referencing.

Comment: @bestsss it is possible to use "class" in the package name by writing a class file directly. it seems the question you really wanted answered was: @Jim can you please provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 17):

A `ClassCircularityError` is thrown when some class is a (direct or indirect) superclass of itself, some interface (directly or indirectly) extends itself or similar.

This should normally not occur as a well-behaved compiler will not produce such classes, but using different versions of a library (or using several libraries containing different versions of a class) could bring this problem.

Scan your libraries for double class names, in particular have a look if there are multiple versions of the mentioned `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` class.

Answer (score 1):

A ClassCircularityError is also thrown when an exception occurs during the definition of a class, for example when using a custom class loader.

The exception's type is misleading, but I think you can check the enclosed exception which should reflect what really happened.

(Full disclosure: I write my own class loaders.)

Here is an example:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.LinkageError.<init>(LinkageError.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassCircularityError.<init>(ClassCircularityError.java:53)
```

Here, the StackOverflowError thrown inside my class loader is the actual cause of the problems. No class circularities were involved. Initially I was confused by the message too.

Comment: I suspect that one of the main causes of a Stack Overflow in a class loader is a circular class definition, or at least this is what someone thought when catching this error and converting/wrapping it into a ClassCircularityErrror.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yeah, very possible. Also, it then logically follows that we should rename this website to Class Circularity Errror.