# How to reproduce ClassCircularityError

Tags: java, jvm

Does anyone know how to reproduce `java.lang.ClassCircularityError` other than `throw new ClassCircularityError(...)`? If possible, could you show me an example `main()` program that always occurs the error?

According to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCircularityError.html):

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine detects a circularity in the superclass hierarchy of a class being loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCircularityError thrown by ClassLoader.defineClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179533/classcircularityerror-thrown-by-classloader-defineclass) (maybe)

Comment: If possible, I would like to know a case the error always occurs.

Comment: The answer to the linked question mentions what causes the error to be thrown. Is that not enough to reproduce it?

Comment: It mention complex project, no details

Comment: Yes. I think so too. I understand the answer but ...

Comment: You can’t produce that error with ordinary code, as the compiler will reject that at compile time. The minimum you would have to do, is to change at least one class afterwards and compile without the others.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error will not normally happen unless the version of some library used in run-time does not match the version of the library used for compilation.

You can easily reproduce the error using separate compilation.

First, compile `A.java` with the following definition:

```
class B {}
class A extends B {}
```

Then compile `B.java` with the reverse class hierarchy:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

Finally, combine `A.class` from the first compilation with `B.class` from the second compilation. After that, an attempt to run either class will result in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: A
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```